# An identity of Riemann zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, riemann-zeta

The Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for complex numbers whose real part is greater than $1$ is given by
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^s}$$
I came across an interesting problem :
Show that $$ {\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}_{gcd(m,n)=1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2} = \frac{\zeta^2(2)}{\zeta(4)}$$

I know that if $a(1)=0$ and $a(n)=k$ when the prime decomposition of $n$ consists $k$ distict prime factors then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{a(n)}}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta^2(s)}{\zeta(2s)}
$$
But many attempts of mine were futile to conquer the above problem. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Note that LHS would be $\zeta^2(2)$ if you allow arbitrary pairs $(m,n)$; grouping them on their gcd $d$ show that you get $S$ for $d=1$ and $(\zeta(4)-1)S$ for $d\geq 2$ so conclude